# Laravel relationship hasMany not working

Tags: laravel, error-handling, relationships

I want to print the name of the user by finding it with 'finished_by' column where id of user is stored. but i get this error:

> Trying to get property 'name' of non-object

Inventory model has `finished_by` which has user ID.

This is mine blade.php

```
@foreach($inventories as $inventory)
    <tr>
      <td>{{$inventory['id']}}</td>
      <td>{{$inventory->user->name}}</td>   
    </tr>
@enforeach
```

and my index method

```
$company_id = Auth::user()->company_id;
$inventories = Inventory::where('company_id',$company_id)->get();

return view('inventories', compact('inventories', 'companies'));
```

And mine relationships

Inventory.php

```
public function users(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'finished_by');
}
```

User.php

```
public function inventories(){
    return $this->hasMany(Inventory::class, 'finished_by');
}
```

Comment: change to `{{$inventory->users->name}}`

Comment: Nothing changed, I have same error.

Comment: show your table schema here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First change your relationship**

Inventory.php

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo("App\User", 'finished_by');
}
```

User.php

```
public function inventories(){
    return $this->hasMany("App\Inventory", 'finished_by');
}
```

You need to add `user` relationship in eager loading

```
$inventories = Inventory::where('company_id',$company_id)->with('user')->get();
```

> Now Template Rendering

```
@foreach($inventories as $inventory)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$inventory->id}}</td>
        <td>
           @if($inventory->user)
              {{$inventory->user->name}}
           @else
              'No User'
           @endif
        </td>   
    </tr>
@enforeach
```

Comment: Changed everything and it's still same

Comment: do you have user with that `finished_by` field, check it once

Comment: @NemanjaZolak code has nothing wrong. for one of your `$inventory` there null users thats why you are getting that error. just add one check there `@if($inventory->user)` then only print name

Comment: yeah that was the problem, it's working after I put @if statement, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do not know exactly what fields you have but test this code :

```
@foreach($inventories as $inventory)
    <tr>
        <td>id : {{$inventory['id']}}</td>
        <td>name : {{$inventory->users->toArray()['name']}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I got this error after making those changes `Call to a member function toArray() on null`

Comment: I put @if statement and its working. Thanks, can you explain me why it has to use toArray()?

Comment: Yes, using `@IF`, you can prevent the error.
I used `toArray` for simplicity and got the output into an array.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you've defined **users** in Inventory model but you've called **user** in your blade file so you must change your function to:

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'finished_by');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the code of controller // you need to add the relationship

```
$inventories = Inventory::where('company_id',$company_id)->with('user')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$company_id = Auth::user()->company_id;
$inventories = Inventory::where('company_id',$company_id)->get();

return view('inventories', compact('inventories', 'companies'));
```